# How to run multiple node.js processes in the same vps and map them to different urls in the same domain?

Tags: node.js

### I would like to have a directory like this:

- apps

  - game01
  - game02
  - game03
  - app01

And when someone goes to my "domain.com/game01" will be managed by the node instance that runs game01.

---

### Node solution:

- I don't like to use nginx because adds another layer of settings to the machine, so when I want to change to another machine I have to configure nginx too and I would like to don't have to.
- I would like to have some kind of versioning of my configuration file.
- I understand that nginx is more secure and performant;

---

### Why should I need to have multiple instances of node and not just one to handle all apps:

- Every app (game01, game02) might have sockets attached too. So I would like to run the same code in the development settings. I want to run minimal different code in the production than in development.

---

### What I'm thinking:

Create a new node.js application where runs on port 443 (because some of them need ssl) and when someone requests (domain.com/game01) will create a new node.js instance with forever and will delegate to this one.

What do you think about my solution? What flaws might have?
What is the best suggestion for this?

(If you can tell my that nginx is a lot better than this solution I might try the nginx solution, at least some versioning)

thanks (:

Comment: You're suggesting creating a new process for every game? If they're super busy, you're just going to thrash the CPU by context switching unnecessarily between lots of processes.

Answer (score 1):

Write a reverse proxy as the main request handler using the [http-proxy](https://npmjs.org/package/http-proxy) module. You can have each game running it's own app server and listening for HTTP requests on the loopback IP with an assigned port. The proxy just maps incoming request paths (/game01) to back end server port numbers (3001, for example).

Comment: can you explain in more detail? thanks

Comment: Nope, sorry. Post a code snippet. Try something.